# What's the difference between IDelegateEvent and IEvent in F#?

Tags: f#

The docs say:

F# gives special status to non-virtual instance member properties compatible with type IDelegateEvent, generating approriate .NET metadata to make the member appear to other .NET languages as a .NET event.

But the behavior of IDelegateEvent and IEvent appears to be the same with or without the CLIEvent attribute.

I'm using 1.9.7.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IEvent inherits from IDelegateEvent, but puts an additional constraint on the type of delegate allowed (forcing it to return unit).  IEvent also inherits from IObservable.  Unless you want to have an event with a weird type, there's no reason to rely on the base IDelegateEvent interface instead of the more common IEvent.

What do you mean when you say that `[<CLIEvent>]` doesn't make a difference?  In FSI there is a bug which prevents events from being generated correctly on the type (e.g. as seen via `Type.GetEvents()`), but events are generated correctly when the code is compiled.   Even is FSI you should see the add_ and remove_ methods being generated when you apply the `[<CLIEvent>]` attribute, though.

Comment: I think the docs are misleading. The paragraph quoted above seems to indicate you should use IDelegateEvent if you want an ordinary .NET event, otherwise use IEvent. It sounds as if IDelegateEvent absolves the need to use the CLIEvent attribute.

Comment: To answer your question...and expand on my previous comment...IDelegateEvent and IEvent appear the same to other .NET languages with or without the CLIEvent attribute. They both work fine, but the docs seem to indicate there's a difference (perhaps that difference being that IDelegateEvent doesn't need the CLIEvent attribute, which is apparently wrong).

Answer (score 4):

I think that in some historic versions of F#, you would use `IDelegateEvent` for standard .NET events and `IEvent` for F# events. The `CLIEvent` attribute was added more recently (because the original solution had quite a few issues). So, I think the `IDelegateEvent` is very rarely useful now (**kvb** mentioned some more specific differences).

A more interesting difference is between `IEvent<'T>` which is an event with handler `Handler<'T>` (which is defined somewhere in F# libraries, I believe) and `IEvent<'Del, 'T>` which can be used with any handlers, for example `IEvent<EventHandler, EventArgs>` which appears quite frequently in .NET libraries...